# alternative for min attribute for all browsers versions and types

Tags: html, forms, validation, browser, min

```
<input id="mobile" max="11" name="mobile" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Mobile')" onfocus="clickclear(this, 'Mobile')" value="Mobile" type="text" style="width: 70px; float: left;color:#888;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">
```

i am using min and max property but its not working on any browser ,
used  pattern tag also but it works on specific browsers,
JavaScript is not an option.

i have JavaScript working and want to replace it with html code only .
Also have server side validation on php . 
only seeking for any addiional html method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a text box make use of maxlength and minlength in place of min and max. Hope this helps

Like - `<input type="text" name="quantity" minlength="2" maxlength="5">`

Or make use of Number Type - `<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">` to input numbers

Comment: i tried it but it dose not  work on all browses (firefox) and their older versions not too much older.